# HTML Section should be centered in the middle of an image on resizing

Tags: html, css

I've tried all the examples I found. I have a div which is positioned in the middle  in front of an image. But when the screen resizes the div doesn't stay as it should. Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong? My code looks like this:

My HTML:

```
  <section class="SliderOuter">
    <img src="images/cover.png" alt="">
    <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
      <div class="tags1">
        <img src="images/ESCO_logo_big.png" alt="">
        <h3 style="color:#ffff">Leading company in the fiel of energy efficiency</h3>
        <br>
        <h4 style="color:#ffff">Be the first to know about ESCO updates and announcements:</h4>
        <form action="" method="post" role="form">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="your@email.com">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-large btn btn-danger" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

My CSS:

```
.tags1 {
    margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Please help!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you explain whats not working. Ideally via a codepen/jsfiddle/SO snippet

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6scgT.jpg - correct one
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqIa1.jpg - resized 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnzf9.jpg - resized 2

Here are some screenshots what I mean

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood this correctly your problem is not with the `.tags` div but with its parents `.container` and `.SliderOuter`

.container needs some positioning applied to it so that it sits within .SliderOuter and yet over the first image.

.Slider in turn needs positioning set on it so that .container can have its height relative to that.

Your CSS eventually should look something like this...

```
.SliderOuter {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tags1 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've thrown together a Fiddle here [http://jsfiddle.net/2owysubj/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/2owysubj/1/)

For the fiddle I took the liberty of tidying up the markup a little (you should try to avoid using inline styles and `<br>` for styling purposes and I've used some dummy images to demonstrate, but the general principal is all there.

Another thing to think about might be to substitute the first image with a background image so you can remove the need to have `.container` absolutely positioned.

You could also look into using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for centring elements, but for what you need right now positioning works perfectly well.

Comment: I've included images in a comment above to show whats the problem. Your solution is not working, unfortunately

Comment: In the example I have given the image, text and form all sit centrally to the parent element with its larger image what ever the size of the parent `<section>`. If that's not what you want, you may need to provide more of the code you are using. In particular the CSS as we only have one block to go on here. Plus any links to the cover.png and ESCO_logo_big.png images would be most helpful to drop in a codepen or a fiddle to demo something closer to what you are after.

Comment: Thinking about it a little further if you want to stop the foreground image overflowing the background image if/when it becomes too deep setting the larger image as a background-image using `background-image:cover;` may help.